# Angular 2 Host in Apache Server issue?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to build angular 2 project and host in apache server ,  [tutorial found from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA-MfYWLLhg)

and the tutorial project result(according to this tutorial it will generate files in dist folder when we build using "ng build --prod") not working in php server it only showing loading message, and in console this errors 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
inline.33006aa0c7f9271418c2.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.42e5fd1daf31343420a1.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
polyfills.017b29d939c6479e18cc.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.9e7a0f6b9f9c8c0e49ba.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.42e5fd1daf31343420a1.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` 
 How to solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

after changing  `<base href="/"> to <base href="./">`  problem solved